# Common view using content query part

Tags: content-query-web-part

1. The master document library has 100's of documents (with taxonomy as one of its metadata)
2. Based on the the taxonomy selection i need to show only few documents in a separate view.
3. The user should be able to  check-out and check-in documents from the view itself.

How to create a webpart to meet the above scenario?

Comment: Just a thought. Why don't you use the built in view functionality of document libraries?